# rendering an Image to a JPanel

Tags: java

I am currently trying to render an Image to a JPanel. Here is my Code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ScreenSaver extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 001;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScreenSaver();
    }
    public ScreenSaver() {
        new Window(1600, 900, "ScreenSaver", this);
    }
    
    public Image ball;

    public  void initCode() {
      try {
          File pathToBall = new File("ball.png");
          ball = ImageIO.read(pathToBall);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      renderImage()
    }
 
    public void renderImage(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(ball, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
    }
}
```

The "initCode()" method gets called after the JFrame has loaded. My problem now is that I want to call the "renderImage()" method. In the parameters I have to put "Graphics g" to use the "g.drawImage" function. Sadly I now dont know what to put in the brackets when I want to call "renderImage()". Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The painting of pictures and graphic elements works a little differently than in your question.

Here is a working example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintExample extends JFrame{

    private BufferedImage ball;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintExample();
    }

    public PaintExample(){
        initCode();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1600, 900));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        add(new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(ball, 0, 0, 100, 100, this);                
            }
        });
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Paint Example");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public  void initCode() {
        try {
            File pathToBall = new File("ball.png");
            ball = ImageIO.read(pathToBall);
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I know this answer is a bit late, but that's because I took a little break from learning Java. Thanks a lot! This definitly helps.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is event driven, this means that you never directly call painting methods.
Basics for a custom painting component:

- extends JComponent
- override paintComponent(Graphics g), this is the point where you can put your rendering code
- override getPreferredSize(), so that the layout managers can do their duty, a suitable value is your image size

In addition I don't understand this line:

```
new Window(1600, 900, "ScreenSaver", this);
```

Comment: the "new Window();" line is the line that creates the JFrame | 
But lets say in a Game, where you render the sprites many times a second, how am I supposed to draw the Sprites there?

Comment: Ok, so this is your Window class, not the one from the standard library, right? In a game, you should trigger the GUI update, when you need to redraw, using the repaint() method, but note that is is not done in realtime, is just a request to schedule a repaint in the Swing thread, as soon as possible.